# Setting a Global Variable in TikZ Loop

Tags: tikz-pgf

I made the drawing below by copying the following lines repeatedly:

```
\tikzmath{\r=\r/2;\c=\r/sqrt(2);}
\draw (-\c, \c) circle (\r);
\draw (\c, -\c) circle (\r);
```

To simplify my code, I tried to enclose these lines in a for-loop insead (shown below), but this didn't work. I consulted the TikZ v3.01a manual, which states on p.901:

> Note that in each execution of `<commands>` the `<commands>` are put in a TEX group. This means that
>   local changes to counters inside `<commands>` do not persist till the next iteration. For instance, if you
>   add 1 to a counter inside `<commands>` locally, then in the next iteration the counter will have the same
>   value it had at the beginning of the first iteration. You have to add `\global` if you wish changes to
>   persist from iteration to iteration.

So this tells me I need to set `r` and `c` to be global variables, but it never says how do that. Can anyone explain?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%Packages Used
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
% -- Failing Code
\begin{tikzpicture}

%defining variables
\def\r{7}
\def\c{0}

\draw (\c,\c) circle (\r);

\foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5,6}
{
\tikzmath{\r=\r/2;\c=\r/sqrt(2);}
\draw (-\c, \c) circle (\r);
\draw (\c, -\c) circle (\r); 
}
\end{tikzpicture}

% -- End Failing Code
\end{document}
```

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Welcome! Don't do this with `\r` and `\c`: pick better names if you need them to be global. Or use `remember`. In any case, please make your code compilable as that's much more helpful than a mere fragment.

Comment: Neat, using remember worked really nicely!  Remember was hiding on p. 904.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you want with the initial definitions, but probably you don't need to make anything global. Instead, just use `remember` for the loop. For example,

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  %defining variables
  \def\r{7}
  \def\c{0}

  \draw (\c,\c) circle (\r);

  \foreach \x [remember=\r as \rlast (initially 7)] in {1,2,3,4,5,6}
  {
    \tikzmath{\r=\rlast/2;\c=\r/sqrt(2);}
    \draw (-\c, \c) circle (\r);
    \draw (\c, -\c) circle (\r); 
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: iterated circles]

If you did need global variables, you would definitely want to choose names other than `\r` and `\c` as you are probably overwriting existing macros with `\def`. That probably doesn't matter within the picture, but may well matter outside.

EDIT

Re. comments: you might want something like

```
\def\rorig{7}
```

...

```
\draw (\c,\c) circle (\rorig);

\foreach \x [remember=\r as \rlast (initially \rorig)] in {1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

Comment: Remember makes defining r=7 redundant, but I still might as well define c=0 right?

Comment: @EvanRosica Aren't you using both before the loop starts?

Comment: yes, but only once, in `\draw (\c,\c) circle (\r);`so i might as well hard code it... unless there is a way to write something like this: `\foreach \x [remember=\r as \lastr (initially \r)] in {1,...,6}` - i.e.  set the starting condidition of the loop to be `\r`

Comment: @EvanRosica Please see edit above. I'd suggest using a different name. Otherwise things get really confusing. (You can reuse `\r`. I just think it unnecessarily borrows trouble.)